# ClickOnce setup.exe is suddenly getting corrupted

Tags: .net, installation, clickonce

We've been using the ClickOnce installer (in Visual Studio 2008) for some time with no problem. We use the option to create a setup program to install prerequisite components.

Now, in the last month or so, the setup.exe file generated each time we publish sometimes does not work. It happened a couple times and was quickly fixed by simply re-publishing. Now it seems to be more permanent when it happens, and a reboot is required to get a working setup.exe.

The bad setup file displays a pair of dialog boxes with no text (see screenshot). Clicking OK causes the setup to exit, and nothing gets installed. Also, the setup.exe file is about half the size of a working copy. Nothing I do seems to enable a working copy to be generated.

[image]

Comment: do you get any build errors or messages when you publish? who has to reboot, the client or the PC that you are using to publish the app?

Comment: Make sure you're publishing in Release mode

Comment: @pSattele No build errors. The project (executable) builds correctly; it is only the setup.exe file that is bad, and that is only created by the VS ClickOnce publish process. Same results whether in Release or Debug mode (you can publish a project in Debug mode, but setup.exe is still bad). Rebooted the developer's machine and setup.exe is now created correctly.

Comment: Nothing like adding reboot first to your build process... You can try deleting everything in the obj\release folder that is under your project. Or Right click on the project and click Clean. If one of those works you can at least put that in a .bat file that gets executed when you build.

Comment: And nothing like troubleshooting an error that pops up every 8 months or so... Happened again today. Closed VS and deleted everything in obj and bin folders. Redid build/publish and it works! So at least I don't need to reboot. Deleting some files in obj required elevated permissions, so maybe a permissions issue? Thanks for your help @PhilSattele